# How to get multiple outputs from multiple jquery ajax get requests when loading page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I am trying to get fetch two data resources. I have tried using get request inside the success function of the first get request, but it seems as if they override somehow and I only get the data from the second request. Here is the code:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $.get({
           url: "/WebProjekat/rest/users",
           success: function(data) {
              //do something with data
              $.get({
                 url: "/WebProjekat/rest/articles/mostPopular",
                 success: function(data) {
                    //do something with data
                 }
              })
           }
        })
    })
```

Am I making a mistake somewhere? Can this even be done in this way and if not, what is the alternative solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check in console network tab you will find your ajax requests so can track what is going on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is there is a scope issue. When you call on the second request, you are using the parameter 'data' for the return value while there is alread a parameter 'data' in scope from the  first request. Hence the content of the parameter 'data' will be overwritten by the second request.

So rename the parameter in your second request to something else - f.e. data2 - and see the result change to the desired one.

Comment: You are absolutely right ! I thought that it wouldn't matter because it is called inside the success function, so the data for the first get request would do what needs to be done and then call the second get request. Nevertheless, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you sending second request in success function you can get data with second reuqest also do as below if your second request does not use response of first request

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.get({
       url: "/WebProjekat/rest/users",
       success: function(data) {
          //do something with data

       }
    })
    $.get({
       url: "/WebProjekat/rest/articles/mostPopular",
       success: function(data) {
          //do something with data
       }
    })
})
```

Comment: please mark answer as right if it solved your problem

Comment: I get the same outcome, the success function of the second get request gets executed while the first is not. I understand that HTTP requests are asynchronous but that doesn't mean that the first success function shouldn't be executed at all. At least by my understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

// Keep the url for testing and then replace.
// Follow the network tab for details:

```
var ajaxFunction = function(url){
return $.ajax({
type:'GET',
url:url
})
}

ajaxFunction('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then(function(data){
    console.log(data); 
    ajaxFunction('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2').then(function(data){
        console.log(data)
    });
},

function(error){
alert('Error reason:'+error)
}
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As it seems like you're just trying to run two calls without actually using data from one to start the other -

another option, for maybe a little cleaner code, is to use jQuery's `jQuery.when()`. It allows you to call two ajax calls (or any async process) and then do something with their responses when both are complete.

I'm just lifting this example straight out of the docs:

```
$.when( $.ajax( "/page1.php" ), $.ajax( "/page2.php" ) ).done(function( a1, a2 ) {
  // a1 and a2 are arguments resolved for the page1 and page2 ajax requests, respectively.
  // Each argument is an array with the following structure: [ data, statusText, jqXHR ]
  var data = a1[ 0 ] + a2[ 0 ]; // a1[ 0 ] = "Whip", a2[ 0 ] = " It"
  if ( /Whip It/.test( data ) ) {
    alert( "We got what we came for!" );
  }
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you try promises. Promises are great for handling async behavior and since jquery 1.5 they have been implemented for $.get, $.post etc

If the two requests are independent of each other, the better solution would be:

```
Promise.all([$.get("/WebProjekat/rest/users").promise(),$.get("/WebProjekat/rest/articles/mostPopular").promise()]).then(function(resultsArray) {
  var users = resultsArray[0];
  var articles = resultsArray[1]
})
.catch(function(err){
  //handle error
})
```

This makes two concurrent calls for one handle.

Only when **both** GET calls are finished will the then function be executed, read more about the `promise.all()` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

[Google chrome has good developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/) for debugging if the rest calls actually returned data.